# How much VirtualBox device/ios emulator/blueStacks informatin can be logged/tracked by servers/ apps?

Tags: web-application, network, webserver, virtualization, logging

This question is intended to know if we can be tricked by Virtual devices emulators. How much logging information can servers/apps request to tell the difference? In the other word, Can we hide our self, that fact that we are using emulators?

it is not about hide the IPs, locations, instead of to distinguish real device or emulators

Comment: I think a word you should search about is fingerprinting. That quite that thing you want to be removed.

Comment: I don't have time to formulate an answer right now, but you can _absolutely_ tell if something is running in a virtual machine as opposed to real metal. There are dozens of ways to do so.